# Intel IOT Code Sample Alarm Clock

Tags: iot, alarm, intel-edison, devkit

Hello I'm new with Intel IoT IDE and I've found this project:

https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/how-to-code-samples/tree/master/alarm-clock/cpp

The problem is that I open it as it says in my eclipse IDE but  when building it has an error:

> ../src/src/services/transports/m2x/../../util.h:27:46: fatal error:
>   websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp: No such file or directory

I've download all websocketpp and I dont know how to solve that error. I've tried adding it to build etc.

I don't know if the workspace must be in a special folder or what...

Anyone can help?
(Using Intel Edison on WINDOWS)

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure if the project was successfully deployed into the board?

I never use Eclipse to develop my projects but you need check if the path are right when the IDE did the deploy and in some cases have super user access.

Comment: The project obviously didn't compile.  Why would it have made it to the board?